# Convert Json object output to Jquery array format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Below is the Json output i am getting on Client Side:

```
jsonp1363710839478({"Comment":[{"Author":"Plan_A","CommentText":"AI like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking","Title":"AMaking hay when the sun shines"},{"Author":"Plan_B","CommentText":"I like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking","Title":"Making hay when the sun shines"}]});
```

How to convert this to the example below:

```
var sample= [
                       { Title: "The Red Violin", Author: "1998" },
                       { Title: "Eyes Wide Shut", Author: "1999" },
                      { Title: "The Inheritance", Author: "1976" }
                      ];
```

Below is my full code:

Code behind:

```
   [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public CommentList GetComments()
    {
        Comments oComment1 = new Comments();
        oComment1.Title = "AMaking hay when the sun shines";
        oComment1.Author = "Plan_A";
        oComment1.CommentText = "AI like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

        Comments oComment2 = new Comments();
        oComment2.Title = "Making hay when the sun shines";
        oComment2.Author = "Plan_B";
        oComment2.CommentText = "I like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

        CommentList oCommentList = new CommentList();
        oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment1);
        oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment2);

        return oCommentList;
    }
```

Client Call Jquery:

```
 $('#CommentsButton').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/GetComments?callback=?', function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.Comment.length; i++) {

                alert(data.Comment[i].Author);


            }

        });
```

I am new to Jquery so detail explanation/code would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to change what the client receives?

Comment: @nickslash yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public Comments[] GetComments()
 {
    .....
    return new Comments[]{oComment1, oComment2};
 }
```

**EDIT**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Comments[] GetComments()
{
    Comments oComment1 = new Comments();
    oComment1.Title = "AMaking hay when the sun shines";
    oComment1.Author = "Plan_A";
    oComment1.CommentText = "AI like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

    Comments oComment2 = new Comments();
    oComment2.Title = "Making hay when the sun shines";
    oComment2.Author = "Plan_B";
    oComment2.CommentText = "I like hay almost as much as I like sun. Just joking";

    return new Comments[]{oComment1, oComment2};
}
```

Comment: @Khan I just changed the return type and added a line after `oComment2.CommentText=.....` . Below lines can be removed

Answer (score 0):

Any reason the data in your JSON response bears no relation to that of your second code example?

Do you not just need to omit the fields you dont want (`CommentText`) and change the value of the comment text?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public CommentList GetComments()
{
    Comments oComment1 = new Comments();
    oComment1.Title = "Your Title";
    oComment1.Author = "Your Date";

    Comments oComment2 = new Comments();
    oComment2.Title = "Your Title";
    oComment2.Author = "Your Date";

    Comments oComment2 = new Comments();
    oComment3.Title = "Your Title";
    oComment3.Author = "Your Date";

    CommentList oCommentList = new CommentList();
    oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment1);
    oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment2);
    oCommentList.Comment.Add(oComment3);

    return oCommentList;
}
```